# Render multiple React components from conditional statements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `definition` object where depending on the ‘type’ of each form, I render a specific component. For example:

```
const definition = 
{
name: "test", 
id: 1,
form: [
  {type: "text"}, 
  {type: "checkbox"}, 
  {type: "radio"}]
};
```

So to access the form types Im just doing a simple map:

```
const definitionTypes = definitions.form.map ( form => form.type )
```

I now have an array of all the form type’s entries stored on `definitionTypes` and I have three components that needs to render depending on which keyword is in that definitionTypes array. So for the “text” I have a component that Im importing called `<DefinitionText />` ,  etc.

Where Im am experiencing problems is figuring out a solution to return multiple components based on the types that are in the definitionTypes array. The end goal would be for these 3 components to render from that array:

```
  // if definitionTypes includes "text" then render...
  <DefinitionText />

  // also if definitionTypes includes "checkbox" then render...
  <DefinitionCheckbox />

  // also if definitionTypes includes "radio" then render...
  <DefinitionRadio />
```

I’ve tried using an `if/else` statement to push each component to a `results` variable then rendering that but the `results` variable sends back an error. Any help in getting multiple components to render based off conditions would be a huge help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having that `defintionTypes` array, the rest should be kinda straightforward... You could use a switch statement for example. Check out the snippet.

```js
function Radio(){
  return <input type='radio'></input>
}
function Text(){
  return <input type='text'></input>
}
function CheckBox(){
  return <input type='checkBox'></input>
}
function App(){
const definitionTypes = ['text', 'checkBox', 'radio']
return <div>
  {definitionTypes.map(type => {
    switch(type){
      case 'text':
        return <Text/>
        break
      case 'radio':
        return <Radio/>
        break
      case 'checkBox':
        return <CheckBox/>
        break
      default:
        break
  }})}
</div>
}
ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id='root'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly build an object map of your components:

```
const Components = {
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar
};
```

Then access using the string for key name:

```
const DynamicComponent = Components[componentName];

<DynamicComponent />
```

Quick example using your map within a component

```
{definitions.form.map( form => {
  const DynamicComponent = Components[form.type];
  return <DynamicComponent />
})}
```